# Dynamic allocation of union of structs

Tags: c, struct, unions

I am trying to create a union of 2 structs (dfp and affine) and want to allocate them dynamically. I am getting errors in creating particular struct array inside union. Am I declaring union in right way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct{
    int fp;
}dfp;

struct{
    int scale;
    int zp;
}affine;

union{
    struct dfp *df;
    struct affine *af;
}quant;

struct member{
    int total;
    union quant arr;
};

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    struct member* ptr;
    ptr = (struct member *)malloc(sizeof(struct member));
    
    
    ptr->total = 2;
    int type = 0;
    if(!type){
        ptr->arr->df = (struct dfp*)malloc(ptr->total*sizeof(struct dfp));   //error
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            ptr->arr->df->fp[i] = 10;
        }
    }
    else{
        ptr->arr->af = (struct affine*)malloc(ptr->total*sizeof(struct affine));   //error
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            ptr->arr->af->scale[i] = 10;
            ptr->arr->af->zp[i] = 20;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a union of structs. It's a union of pointers.

Comment: "*I am getting errors*". It would make sense to give the exact errors.

Comment: `sizeof(struct dfp)`. There is no type `struct dfp`. You have a variable called `dfp` that has the type of an anonymous/unnamed type. Change the struct definitions to be like: `struct dpf {int fp;};`

Comment: Also `ptr->arr->df` is wrong. `arr` is not a pointer. So you need `ptr->arr.df`. `ptr->arr->df->fp[i]` is also wrong. `fp` is not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most issues have already been pointed out by others separately. This is my attempt at writing a complete answer with explanations and advice.

- First off, please check your exact compiler warnings and errors. These are your best help in resolving these kind of issues.
- The program does not contain a union of structs, but a union of *pointers* to structs.
- The program's definitions are not correct. Taking `dfp` as an example. This, `struct { int fp; } dfp;`, defines an *anonymous struct* with the the variable name `dfp`. The name of the struct should go before the struct declaration list, e.g. `struct dfp { int fp; };`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) or see the C standard specifications.
- Judging by the code in `main`, the member variables of the structs should be arrays of size 2 instead of single `int`s.
- The operator `->` is for "member access using a pointer". Since `arr` is not a pointer, use a dot (`.`) to access its members. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access).
- Dynamically allocated memory must be free'd, or else the program will have one or more memory leaks.

Here is the full code with all mentioned corrections:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dfp {
    int fp[2];
};

struct affine {
    int scale[2];
    int zp[2];
};

union quant {
    struct dfp *df;
    struct affine *af;
};

struct member {
    int total;
    union quant arr;
};

int main(void) {
    struct member* ptr;
    ptr = (struct member *)malloc(sizeof(struct member));
    
    ptr->total = 2;
    int type = 0;
    if(!type) {
        ptr->arr.df = (struct dfp*)malloc(ptr->total*sizeof(struct dfp));
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            ptr->arr.df->fp[i] = 10;
        }
    }
    else {
        ptr->arr.af = (struct affine*)malloc(ptr->total*sizeof(struct affine));
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            ptr->arr.af->scale[i] = 10;
            ptr->arr.af->zp[i] = 20;
        }
    }

    if(!type) {
        free(ptr->arr.df);
    }
    else {
        free(ptr->arr.af);
    }
    free(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct the struct definition as below:

```
struct dfp {
    int fp;
};

struct affine{
    int scale;
    int zp;
};
```